# Weak closure of subsets of the unitary sphere of a Banach space.

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces, weak-topology

Assume that $(X,\|\cdot\|)$ is a Banach space with $\|\cdot\|$ strictly convex. Define $S=\{x\in X:\|x\|=1\}$. Suppose that $\varepsilon>0$ and $x_0\in S$ and define
$$
B_\varepsilon=\{x\in X:\|x-x_0\|\le\varepsilon\}\cap S.
$$
Consider the following problem:

> Can we find $y\in X$ such that $\|y\|<1$ and any line which contains $y$ must intersect $B_\varepsilon$?

Now consider the following possible solution:

Take a [supporting hyperplane](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Supporting_hyperplane) $H$ for the convex set $B=\{x\in X:\|x\|\le 1\}$ at the point $x_0$. Once $\|\cdot\|$ is strictly convex, one can find $z\in X\setminus\{0\}$ such the set
$$
H_z=\{h+z:h\in H\},
$$
has the property that $H_z\cap B_\varepsilon\neq \emptyset$ and $H_z\cap B_\varepsilon=H_z\cap S$. Now let $Q$ be the region enclosed by $H_z$ and $B_\varepsilon$. It follows that if $y\in Q$, then any line which contains $x$ must intersect $B_\varepsilon$.

> Question 1: Is my proof correct?
>
> Question 2: Do you know another proof?

Remark: If $X$ is an infinite dimensional Banach space, then every $y\in Q$ belongs to the weak closure of $B_\varepsilon$.

Remark 1: Cross-Posted: [mathoverflow](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/317349/weak-closure-of-subsets-of-the-unitary-sphere-of-a-banach-space?noredirect=1#comment792218_317349)